# Javascript functions not working with Apex:commandbutton

Tags: apex, javascript

I have two Javascript functions:

```
<script>

function confirmTransfer() {
  var tasks = "{!totalTasks}";
  var matches = "{!totalMatches}";
  var contacts = "{!totalContacts}";

  var transfer = confirm("Are you sure you wish to transfer: " + 
    tasks + " tasks, " + matches + " matches, and " + contacts " contacts?");

  if (transfer) return true;
  return false;
}  

function confirmCancel() {
  var isCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
  if (isCancel) return true;

 return false;
}
</script>
```

for some reason, just the confirmCancel function does what I want it do. The confirmTransfer button simply goes sstraight to the function call in the commandButton:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" 
onclick="return confirmCancel()"immediate="true"/>    
<apex:commandButton action="{!step4}"  value="Transfer" 
onclick="return confirmTransfer()" immediate="true"/>
```

When I click Transfer, I see this in the console: 
`transfercontacts:137 Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmTransfer is not defined`

The syntax is the same, can anyone explain what this could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a `+` here:

contacts **+** " contacts?"